# For the given function, $\lim_{x \to 0} f'(x) = \infty$. Can we say that the tangent line is vertical?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

A query regarding the definition of tangent line:

For example in $f(x)=\sqrt[5]{x^3+x}+\cos^4\left(\sin^2(\pi x)+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ in $x=0$  we have $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)=\infty$. In this case can we say that the tangent line is vertical?

Thank you for your help to clarify my idea on this topic.

Comment: Did you mean diffe**re**ntiable curve?

Comment: Why does the line appear not to be tangent? It appears perfectly tangent to me. If you think the graph cannot cross the tangent line, you’re thinking only of convex/concave functions. Welcome to the notion of an inflection point.

Comment: The tangent at zero is the x-axis. Use a graphing tool instead of doing it by hand.

Comment: Just one question, is it possible for a tangent line to a function to be vertical? Like the last example I put.

Comment: I suspect you did not intend to say that $f(x)=0$. You should edit that.

Comment: The two sided limit at $0$ does not exist unless you use $\ln|x|$ but $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f'(x)=\infty$ so it has a vertical tangent at $0$.